# Dynamically show the tool tip on select option

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show a tool tip in the following format dynamically using JavaScript:

```html
Emp Details First Name :FirstName-1 Last Name :lastName1 Emp Id :empID 11

<select name="opts" id="empdetil" multiple>
  <option title="" value="FirstName-1 lastName1 empID 11">EmpID-11</option>
  <option title="" value="FirstName-2 lastName2 empID 12">EmpID-12</option>
  <option title="" value="FirstName-3 lastName3 empID 13">EmpID-13</option>
  <option title="" value="FirstName-4 lastName4 empID 14">EmpID-14</option>
  <option title="" value="FirstName-5 lastName5 empID 15">EmpID-15</option>
  <option title="" value="FirstName-6 lastName6 empID 16">EmpID-16</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hello, if I understand correctly:  you want to change tooltip text of the element dynamically? Could you be more precise what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you tried for any code?

Comment: i want to show the tool tip from the value , tool tip as to show like "Emp Details /n First Name :FirstName-1 /n Last Name :lastName1 /n Emp Id :empID 11" , this option "<option title="" value="FirstName-1 lastName1 empID 11">EmpID-11</option>" this are creating dynamically